# How to get Specific Array List Item

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel, jbutton

I have a little issue with selecting from an array list. I am writing some code to enable me fix about 10 JButtons in a circle, I got that right, but then ..... I want to set an actionListener on each of the Buttons, but I don't get it, all the buttons inherit the actions required for one. How do I make it specific,... here's my code.... Thanks in advance!

```
private JButton quest;

public Beginner() {

    int n = 10; // no of JButtons
    int radius = 200;
    Point center = new Point(250, 250);
    double angle = Math.toRadians(360 / n);

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    points.add(center);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double theta = i * angle;
        int dx = (int) (radius * Math.sin(theta));
        int dy = (int) (radius * Math.cos(theta));
        Point p = new Point(center.x + dx, center.y + dy);
        points.add(p);
    }

    draw(points);

}

public void draw(List<Point> points) {

    JPanel panels = new JPanel();

    SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();

    // Layout used
    int count = 1;
    for (Point point : points) {

        quest = new JButton("Question " + count);
        quest.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        Font fonte = new Font("Script MT Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        quest.setFont(fonte);

        add(quest);
        count++;

        spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, quest, point.x, SpringLayout.WEST, panels);

        spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, quest, point.y, SpringLayout.NORTH, panels);

        setLayout(spring);

        panels.setOpaque(false);
        panels.setVisible(true);
        panels.setLocation(10, 10);

        add(panels);

        // action Listener to be set on individual buttons
        quest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

                if (quest.equals(points.get(5)))
                    ;
                String c = "Hello!";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want each button to have it's own unique action when clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that expression

```
if (quest.equals(points.get(5)));
```

does nothing. I guess it should be rewritten like this

```
if (quest.equals(points.get(5))) {
    String c = "Hello!";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c);
}
```

Comment: @Presh_K7 no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I am understanding the question is that you have multiple buttons and you would like each button to have it's own action associated with it. There are a couple ways to go about doing this. Either you create a new ActionListener for each JButton depending which button you are creating.

You can also create a large case/switch or if/else within the ActionListener that gets determined by which button was selected. To do this you can call the getActionCommand() function for the ActionEvent object.

```
quest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

            if (a.getActionCommand().equals("Question 1"))
            {
                String c = "Hello!";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c);
            }
            else if(a.getActionCommand().equals("Question 2"))
            {
                //have it do something else
            }
            //and so on so forth

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink the entire design. You have this line:

```
if (quest.equals(points.get(5))) {
```

But `points` is a list containing Point objects; `points.get(5)` returns a Point. 
quest is a JButton. How can a JButton instance equal a Point instance?

Comment: The points thing is connected to an array list.... upon which the JButton is built!!!